# php doing curl in loop will slow down server?

Tags: php, curl, wordpress, libcurl

If I have a loop with a lot of curl executions happening, will that slow down the server that is running that process? I realize that when this process runs, and I open a new tab to access some other page on the website, it doesn't load until this curl process that's happening finishes, is there a way for this process to run without interfering with the performance of the site?

For example this is what I'm doing:

```
foreach ($chs as $ch) {
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    ... do random stuff...
}
```

I know I can do multi curl, but for the purposes of what I'm doing, I need to do it like this.

**Edit:**

Okay, maybe this might change things a bit but I actually want this process to run using WordPress cron. If this is running as a WordPress "cron", would it hinder the page performance of the WordPress site? So in essence, if the process is running, and people try to access the site, will they be lagged up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested it and it looks like the multi curl process running on WP's "cron" made no noticeable negative impact on the site's performance. I was able to load multiple other pages with no terrible lag on the site while the site was running the multi curl process. So looks like it's okay. And I also made sure that there is locking so that this process doesn't get scheduled multiple times. And besides, this process will only run once a day in U.S. low-peak hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The curl requests are not asynchronous so using curl like that, any code after that loop will have to wait to execute until after the curl requests have each finished in turn.

`curl_multi_init` is PHP's fix for this issue.  You mentioned you need to do it the way you are, but is there a way you can refactor to use that?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

As an alternate, this library is really good for this purpose too: https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl

Comment: Oh... wow.. that sucks o.o.. okay. I guess I'll have to use curl_multi_init. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not likely unless you use a strictly 1-thread server for development.  Different requests are eg in Apache handled by workers (which depending on your exact setup can be either threads or separate processes) and all these workers run independently.

The effect you're seeing is caused by your browser and not by the server.  It is suggested in [rfc 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) that a client only opens a limited number of parallel connections to a server:

> Clients that use persistent connections SHOULD limit the number of
>   simultaneous connections that they maintain to a given server. A
>   single-user client SHOULD NOT maintain more than 2 connections with
>   any server or proxy.

btw, the standard usage of capitalized keywords like here `SHOULD` and `SHOULD NOT` is explained in [rfc 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt)

and that's what eg Firefox and probably other browsers also use as their defaults.  By opening more tabs you quickly exhaust these parallel open channels, and that's what causes the wait.

EDIT: but after reading @earl3s 'reply I realize that there's more to it: earl3s addresses the performance within each page request (and thus the server's "performance" as experienced by the individual user), which can in fact be sped up by parallelizing curl requests.  But at the cost of creating more than one simultaneous link to the system(s) you're querying...  And that's where rfc2616's recommendation comes back into play: unless the backend systems delivering the content are under your control you should think twice before paralleling your curl requests, as each page hit on your system will hit the backend system with n simultaneous hits...

EDIT2: to answer OP's clarification: no (for the same reason I explained in the first paragraph - the "cron" job will be running in another worker than those serving your users), and if you don't overdo it, ie, don't go wild on parallel threads, you can even mildly parallelize the outgoing requests.  But the latter more to be a good neighbour than because of fear to met down your own server.